# SQL Query in two different Rails models that have no association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a landlords table, and `landlord_addresses` table, and a `landlord_companies` table. From the landlords index view and using the landlords_controller I need to be able to search the landlord_companies, BUT landlords and `landlord_companies` have no ActiveRecord association with each other. Obviously I can't use what I've written below, but I am not sure how to search the `landlord_companies` ...any help would be great!

```
@landlord = @landlords.includes(:landlord_company)
   .references(:landlord_companies)
   .where("landlord_companies.llc_name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:landlord_llc_search]}%")
```

Schema:

```
create_table "landlords", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "name"
   t.string   "contact_name"
   t.string   "contact_number"
   t.integer  "listing_agent_id"
   t.boolean  "own_application"
   t.boolean  "own_credit"
   t.boolean  "accepts_roommate_matchups"
   t.boolean  "management_company"
   t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
end

create_table "landlord_companies", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "llc_name"
   t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
   t.integer  "landlord_address_id"
end
```

Comment: based on which condition you want to search landlord companies?

Comment: @uzaif There is an llc_name column in the landlord_companies table that I need to search.

Comment: and there is no association between landlord and landlord_companies ?

Comment: can you show me `schema` of table?

Comment: `.references(:landlord_companies)` remove this and try

Comment: @uzaif There is not an association between landlord and landlord_companies.

I tried to remove .references(:landlord_companies) and that did not work.

Comment: @uzaif I added the schema for those tables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126340/discussion-between-mike-wiesenhart-and-uzaif).

Comment: try this `@landlord.where('company_name=?',params[:company])` than you can access `@landlord.ll_addresss` this

Comment: dont know its work or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out and actually use the SQL query I had already written. I thought there was no association, but technically there was using a through.

Landlord.rb

```
has_many :landlord_companies, through: :landlord_addresses
```